# How to do this query in one query?

Tags: sql

eI don't know if what I want to do is possible, but I am curious.

I have a time table that looks like that

```
timeTable
---------
_id
date
```

I have another table that stored that with timeinfo that is a ForeignKey to the timeTable

```
myTable
-------
action
date_id
```

Now, what I would like to do is updating the date_id with the id of the same date next month.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET date_id =  (SELECT date + interval '1 month' FROM timeTable INNER JOIN myTabe ON _id = date_id)
;
```

I know that this query can't work because the query return a date where it does expect an uuid.

My question : Is it possible to retrieve the date_id of the same date the next month with one query without anohter subquery ? That my actual query I don't see how could I do it. Any idea ?

```
SELECT date + interval '1 month' FROM dimtime INNER JOIN roadmap ON _id = date_id
```

Comment: I´m afraid you´ll have to use a sub querry to get the id. Why don't you want to use a sub query anyway?

Comment: I don't mind that what I am doing. I just though that because + interval '1 month' is something knew I could trick the query. This question is just out of curiosity.

Comment: Your queries list names of the tables which you did not describe. Please edit your question, I can't really understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: @maksymko : Sorry it was a typo. I just did edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

**Edited**

```
UPDATE myTable t1
SET t1.date_id = (SELECT t2._id FROM timeTable t2 WHERE t2.date = (SELECT t3.date + interval '1 month' FROM timeTable t3 WHERE t3._id  = t1.date_id));
```

Comment: This works but that not what I was asking. I was asking on hon to do it without a second subquery. Here your solution uses a second subquery

Comment: Ah, sorry, obviously I didnt read your question thoroughly enough. I wouldn't know another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a nasty hack, but if your RDBMS supports a deterministic conversion between integer and date datatypes, there is a way to do this without any subqueries at all - but it is almost certain to require changes to existing data.

The solution requires that you use the integer representation of the date as the key in `timeTable` (rather than arbitrarily assigned values). If you do this, then you can perform date calcuations without the need to look up the date value from `timeTable`. This removes the need to include `timeTable` in the query at all (unless you need to validate that the new date exists there). In this scenario, pseudo-SQL for your query would become:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET date_id =  to_int(to_date(date_id) + interval `1 month`))
;
```

If the int <-> date conversion is implicit in your RDBMS, it gets even shorter:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET date_id =  date_id + interval `1 month`
;
```

However, if you're at the point where you can choose to implement this design, you might be better off discarding the link `timeTable` and storing a native date type in the target table rather than the integer FK.